# WESB-import-http binding POST method-com.ibm.websphere.sca.ServiceUnavailableException

Tags: websphere-esb

I have a module(Websphere ESB) which contains an import configured with http binding POST method.
I got the below exception when I try to  test

com.ibm.websphere.sca.ServiceUnavailableException

Could not obtain a connection to the destination or Exception was happened on 
the connection. Failed to process the request. Async IO operation failed (3), 
reason: RC: 64  The specified network name is no longer available. Refer to the 
server logs for more information.

Below is the stack trace from ffdc

[10/27/14 14:40:35:121 EDT]     FFDC Exception:com.ibm.websphere.security.EntryNotFoundException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.security.core.WSAccessManager.fillMissingAccessIds ProbeId:1018

com.ibm.websphere.security.EntryNotFoundException

```
at com.ibm.ws.wim.registry.util.UniqueIdBridge.getUniqueGroupId(UniqueIdBridge.java:399)

at com.ibm.ws.wim.registry.WIMUserRegistry$11.run(WIMUserRegistry.java:886)

at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5365)

at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5453)

at com.ibm.ws.wim.security.authz.jacc.JACCSecurityManager.runAsSuperUser(JACCSecurityManager.java:432)

at com.ibm.ws.wim.security.authz.ProfileSecurityManager.runAsSuperUser(ProfileSecurityManager.java:981)

at com.ibm.ws.wim.registry.WIMUserRegistry.getUniqueGroupId(WIMUserRegistry.java:877)

at com.ibm.ws.security.registry.UserRegistryImpl.getUniqueGroupId(UserRegistryImpl.java:627)

at com.ibm.websphere.security._UserRegistry_Stub.getUniqueGroupId(_UserRegistry_Stub.java:635)

at com.ibm.ws.security.core.WSAccessManager.fillMissingAccessIds(WSAccessManager.java:1034)

at com.ibm.ws.security.core.WSAccessManager.addAuthorizationTable(WSAccessManager.java:253)

at com.ibm.ws.security.core.ServerSecurityComponentImpl.install(ServerSecurityComponentImpl.java:696)

at com.ibm.ws.security.core.ServerSecurityComponentImpl.stateChanged(ServerSecurityComponentImpl.java:421)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1079)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectEvent(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1302)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.setState(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:281)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:934)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:740)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1272)

at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5365)

at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5453)

at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1277)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2048)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:385)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:328)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:599)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:561)

at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1184)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)

at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)

at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)

at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)

at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)

at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)

at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)

at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1331)

at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)

at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1224)

at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl._startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1407)

at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1303)

at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1263)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)

at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)

at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)

at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)

at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)

at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)

at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)

at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1331)

at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)

at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1224)

at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)

at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:453)

at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:286)

at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:65)

at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:733)

at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:522)

at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)
```

I created JAAS alias,but still I face the above exception

Comment: The web service which is being invoked is no longer active,so this caused the exception------

The specified network name is no longer available. Refer to the server logs for more information.

Answer (score -2):

I am getting the exact same error. And I am using the HTTP GET url.

**Could not obtain a connection to the destination or Exception was happened on the connection. Failed to process the request. Async IO operation failed (3), reason: RC: 64  The specified network name is no longer available.
Refer to the server logs for more information.**

And the webservice is absolutely fine as it works from other REST clients.
Is there anyway to debug this issue? like what url is it trying to really make call to, because it says "the specified network name is no longer available"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately, this is a comment, and should not be posted as an answer.  Feel free to delete your answer and move the text to a comment.